# how to make an instance of a class callable for multiple times using multiple sets of parentheses in one line

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, callable-object

I would like to implement class 'Add' such that return the sum of the arguments passed in a separate set of parentheses using **call** method and inheritance in python. for example:

```
>>>Add(10)
10
>>>Add(10)(11)
21
>>>Add(10)(11)(12)
33
```

I tried this piece of code do not receive the expected result.

```
class Add():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self, number):
        print(self.a + number)

>>>Add(10)
10
>>>Add(10)(11)
21
```

but for the third time( `Add(10)(11)(12)` ) I received the error 'int object is not callable.'

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE:

As per @jsbueno's suggestion of inheriting `int` will get you what is needed.

```py
class Add(int):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self, number):
        self.a += number # Store the result of your call.
        return self # return the instance back so that you can call it again and again.
```

This would let you use `Add` objects just like any other `int` objects.

```py
>>> Add(10)(11) + Add(12)(13) # Returns 46
```

---

I am surprised with the error message you got : `int object is not callable.`
One would expect you would get `'NoneType' object is not callable`. At least that's what I got when I ran your code.

To achieve what you want to achieve, you need to return the instance back to the call-site, so that you can `__call__` it again.

I would suggesting modifying your code like so:

```py
class Add():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self, number):
        self.a += number # Store the result of your call.
        return self # return the instance back so that you can call it again and again.
```

You can then use it like:

```py
Add(10)(11)(12) # Returns a instance of Add class.
Add(10)(11)(12).a # fetches the result of your calls.
```

Now this would change your original instance of `Add(10)`. If that is not something you would want, you would replace your `__call__` method with:

```py
def __call__(self, number):
    result = self.a + number
    return Add(result)
```

This way, the base `Add` instance never really changes.

```py
base = Add(10)
base.a # Would be 10
new_inst = base(11)(12)
new_inst.a # Would be 33
base.a # Would still be 10
```

Comment: thanks a lot. how can I receive the result without the attribute 'a' (exactly the same output I mentioned in the question)

Comment: I am not aware of any constructs in python that can help you achive both (chaining of calls and getting value directly) at the same time. You could probably implement `__int__` and `__float__`  to return `self.a` and wrap the `Add(10)(11)(12)` in an `int()` or `float()` call get the value directly post chaining.

Comment: Actually, I think that jsut inheriting from `int` and and adding the `__call__` method, as in this answer, shoud do what the O.P. wants. @amd.srinivas - can you give it a try and add the result to  your answer?